# Cannot center a col class inside a row from bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've been doing some bootstrap lately and I stumbled upon a problem. Namely, I use a `container` and nest `row` plus a few `col` classes in it. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-voice-cmz4vn?file=/src/App.js) link. As you can see, I use a `styled` component for the `<Rectangle />` and then I add three of them in the first row and one in the second. However they aren't centered and I tried to center them by adding `align-items` and `mx-auto` but did not make it. [image]
As you can see from the photo, the rectangles inside the `div.row` aren't centered but they're kind of floated on the left. The same thing goes for the second row, it's not centered. The question I have is, is it possible to center these rectangles (`col` classes) inside a `row` class? In this case I added 3x1 but in my scenario, it is dynamic and in some case I'd have 2 rectangles at top + 2 at bottom, 2 at top + 1 at bottom etc. and I need them to center automatically. If possible, how can I achieve it and center them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align items in column, make `.col` **flex** and then you can justify (align) child items.
Add `d-flex justify-content-center` to your columns to align it

```css
.jKVMcY {
  height: 90px;
  width: 115px;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(229, 228, 226);
  border-radius: 7px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container py-3 bg-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="sc-bczRLJ jKVMcY">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="sc-bczRLJ jKVMcY">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="sc-bczRLJ jKVMcY">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```